# List in Python Query

Tags: python, list

```
P = []
P.insert(0,[1,4,8])
P.insert(1,[2,3])
P.insert(4,[5,6,7])
P.insert(8,[9,21])
P.insert(2,[10,11])
P.insert(3,[13,14])
P.insert(6,[17])
P.insert(7,[18,19]) 
P.insert(9,[20])
P.insert(11,[12])
P.insert(14,[15,16])
```

so in this block of code i want to store values shown above at particular locations thats why i used the insert function of python. Facing problem when a null set comes in. in this block of code if you see carefully P.insert(5,) is missing (basically i dont want anything on location 5) but what the code did is when it saw the mssing number 5 it basicallly shifted the 6, 7,8,9 number positions forward by one which i dont want to happen. i know to resolve this problem i would have to define a null set at location 5 to resolve this issue but is there anyother way to resolve this issue without explicitly defining it and the locations i have given remain fixed irrespective of there are list in between or not

I was thinking of using if but not getting how can i use if to tell that if there is null set consider it automatically

Answer (score 0):

- you are using a `list` P to store values at specific locations, when you want to skip a particular location (in this case, location 5), you encounter the issue of `shifting` positions because lists in Python are ordered, and when you insert a new element at a specific `index`, all the elements after that index are shifted to the right.
- You can use conditional statement to check

```
if len(P) < 5:
    P.insert(5, [])
```

- to handle the issue of missing values without explicitly defining a null set, you can use a `dictionary` instead of a `list`. In a dictionary, you can directly assign values to specific keys without worrying about the order.

```
P = {}
P[0] = [1, 4, 8]
P[1] = [2, 3]
P[4] = [5, 6, 7]
P[8] = [9, 21]
P[2] = [10, 11]
P[3] = [13, 14]
P[6] = [17]
P[7] = [18, 19]
P[9] = [20]
P[11] = [12]
P[14] = [15, 16]
```

each key in the `dict` represents the desired location, and the corresponding value is the list to be stored at that location. this way you don't have to worry about missing values or shifting positions when inserting new elements.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @Sauron to use a dictionary is valid.

However, if you insist on using a list then you can achieve your objective by pre-allocating the list.

Something like this:

```
P: list[None|list[int]] = [None] * 15

P[0] = [1,4,8]
P[1] = [2,3]
P[4] = [5,6,7]
# etc

print(P)
```

Comment: can you please explain the first line of code didnt understand it like little explanation

Comment: The first line declares a variable P with a type hint indicating that it will be a list and that the lists's element will be either None or int. The assignment is a list of 15 elements each of which will be None